# Doctrine orderBy with NULL last

Tags: sorting, null, doctrine

I have a table with items I have to sort, where some items having statuses. What I need is:

1. Sort items by status' 'sort' values (ASC)
2. Sort items by timestamp (DESC)
3. Sort all items so that all items without status are last but also sorted by timestamp

Here's what I have:

```
$query->leftJoin('c', 'Statuses', 'st', 'st.id = c.status')
    ->addSelect('CASE WHEN c.status IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as HIDDEN status_is_null')
    ->orderBy('status_is_null', 'asc')
    ->addOrderBy('st.sort', 'asc')
    ->addOrderBy('c.timestamp', 'desc');
```

But it throws an error:

An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT c.id, CASE WHEN c.status IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as HIDDEN status_is_null FROM Items c WHERE c.active = ? ORDER BY status_is_null asc, c.timestamp desc LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0' with params [true]: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'status_is_null FROM Items c WHERE c.active = '1' ORDER BY ' at line 1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure but I think you need to add opening and closing brackets before CASE and after END.

Comment: Nope, still an exception

Comment: I have a simplified solution and it works fine: `$this->createQueryBuilder('a')->select('a.id, CASE WHEN a.field IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HIDDEN h_field')->orderBy('h_field', 'asc')`. Can you post the rest of the things you've done to `$query`? Maybe something there breaks your code.

Comment: it's a pretty long file with lots of query and order options. But it starts with $this->query->select('c.id')->from('Items', 'c');. Should I substitute it with your example?

Comment: Then I would start removing line by line and see what combination works and fix the rest.